# Can you quote a random string without knowing if it contains special characters?

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm having trouble inputting random generated passwords into some scripts.

I generate the password, and paste it between "". But sometimes it contains characters that sends the whole thing crashing down, like " # or whatever.

EDIT: I have been pointed to Quoting for a solution

There are several options for Quoting ( using `\` , `" "` and `' '` ) but each require checking the string for special characters, like single quotes in a single quote block.
Is there a way to really paste a string without needing to check it or is doing that check always necessary when your random string can contain the ' character at least.

Comment: So is there no way to just paste a random string of characters and be treated as such without knowing wether there are " or ' or \ characters in it? You always need to check for those and mask them?

Comment: Excellent edit! I wanted to ask you for it, but then realized it was really me who didn’t read thoroughly enough. Now it’s very clear and I hope my answer helps. :)

Comment: It’s been some time, did you resolve the issue? Does my answer help? Is there anything I can do to improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Here document](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html#redirection):

> This type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the
>   current source until a line containing only delimiter (with no
>   trailing blanks) is seen. (…) If any part of *word* is quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote removal on *word*, and the lines in the here-document are not expanded.

The delimiter (here “EOF”) has to occur on a single line to end the here document and it needs to be quoted in the first line, for example

```
$ cat <<"EOF"
a string \ with ' st$(echo)ra"nge chars?
EOF
```

gives you the literal:

```
a string \ with ' st$(echo)ra"nge chars?
```

To use the string in a script, adjust it to read from stdin and replace `cat` with the script’s path in the example above.

Note that the occurence of the delimiter string inside the password is not a problem, as the delimiter has to be alone on the line. The only way this does not work is if the delimiter matches *exactly* the password string, and as most passwords are created with certain requirements (e.g. “at least one number”) it should be easy to choose a delimiter that simply doesn’t meet one of the requirements. One could use “123456”, with that password failure is *expected*.